# PHP AES Encryption JAVA to PHP - openssl_encrypt

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl

I am using openssl_encrypt function available in PHP to get the similar result as the below java code is producing.

But it is all different. Kindly help me.

JAVA CODE

```
package com.atom.echallan.security.util;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import com.atom.echallan.util.EChallanUtil;


public class AtomAES {

    private String password             = "8E41C78439831010F81F61C344B7BFC7";
    private String salt                 = "200000054575202";
    private static int pswdIterations   = 65536  ;
    private static int keySize          = 256;
    private final byte[] ivBytes        = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };

    public AtomAES(){
        super();
    }

    public String encrypt(String plainText, String key, String merchantTxnId) throws Exception
    {
        this.password = key;
        // salt->200000054575202
        this.salt = merchantTxnId;

        return encrypt(plainText);
    }

    private String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception {

        byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8");

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(
                password.toCharArray(),
                saltBytes,
                pswdIterations,
                keySize
                );

        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

        //encrypt the message
        IvParameterSpec localIvParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); //CBC
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret,localIvParameterSpec);

        byte[] encryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        return  byteToHex(encryptedTextBytes);

    }

    public String decrypt(String encryptedText, String key, String merchantTxnId) throws Exception {
        this.password = key;
        this.salt = merchantTxnId;
        return decrypt(encryptedText);
    }


    private String decrypt(String encryptedText) throws Exception {

        byte[] saltBytes = salt.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] encryptedTextBytes = hex2ByteArray(encryptedText);

        // Derive the key
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(
                password.toCharArray(),
                saltBytes,
                pswdIterations,
                keySize
                );

        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

        // Decrypt the message
        IvParameterSpec localIvParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");//CBC
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret,localIvParameterSpec);


        byte[] decryptedTextBytes = null;
        decryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextBytes);

        return new String(decryptedTextBytes);
    }


  //Converts byte array to hexadecimal String
    private String byteToHex(byte byData[])
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(byData.length * 2);

        for(int i = 0; i < byData.length; i++)
        {
            int v = byData[i] & 0xff;
            if(v < 16)
                sb.append('0');
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(v));
        }

        return sb.toString().toUpperCase();
    }


    //Converts hexadecimal String to array of byte
    private byte[] hex2ByteArray(String sHexData)
    {
        byte rawData[] = new byte[sHexData.length() / 2];
        for(int i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++)
        {
            int index = i * 2;
            int v = Integer.parseInt(sHexData.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
            rawData[i] = (byte)v;
        }

        return rawData;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

        AtomAES aes = new AtomAES();

        String data = "mmp_txn=355106|mer_txn=M123|amt=100.0000|";
        String encData = aes.encrypt(data, EChallanUtil.ATOM_ENCRYPTION_KEY, "178");

        System.out.println("ENC DATA : " + encData);
        System.out.println("DEC DATA : " + aes.decrypt(encData, EChallanUtil.ATOM_ENCRYPTION_KEY, "178"));

    }
}
```

PHP CODE

```
class Encryption {

    public function encrypt($data, $key = "4A8A53E16C9C34EA5E77EF9FF7B2FD04", $method = "AES-256-CBC") {
        $size = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
        $iv = substr($key, 0, 16);
//        string openssl_pbkdf2 ( string $password , string $salt , int $key_length , int $iterations [, string $digest_algorithm ] )

        $hash = openssl_pbkdf2($key,'178','256','65536', 'sha1');
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $hash, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        return bin2hex($encrypted);
    }

    public function decrypt($data, $key, $method) {
        $size = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
        $iv = substr($key, 0, $size);
        $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($data, $method, $key, false, $iv);
        return $decrypted;
    }

    function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize) 
    { 
        $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize); 
        return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad); 
    } 

}

$text = 'mmp_txn=355106|mer_txn=M123|amt=100.0000|';
//
//$enc = new AESEncryption;
//$enc1 = new CbcCrypt;
$enc2 = new Encryption;

echo $enc2->encrypt($text);
```

JAVA Result : 
ENC DATA : `4BBB37555EFFEF677CEF1B5D55843E50255F65540DF16AFB3F2A0B7B91341E54FB0432EEE2154A947DAD013E8C99822D`

PHP Result : `c43ba05ae04f68ae18313bc2042595fc70981e0d9421af9d232a3d17a01b5dd8dd8ce702230f6e49d918c9578f9c6944`

I dont know why it is happening.
Length of the string is same but result are different.
How to get the similar result as in java?

Comment: 1. make sure the generated keys are equal  2. You have different result encoding (hex vs base64). As well you are using differet IV (in both cases IV is used unsafe way)

Comment: Can you please guide me what code should I use for IV in php case to match the result? Thanks

Comment: IV needs to be the same, it is usually random array passed along the ciphertext

Comment: In java case, it is {1,2,3....} I am not getting what should I write in PHP. It should be of 16 bytes and should be a string and Java it is an array... How can I make it same in PHP?

Comment: Can you help me with code? Thanks for your help..

Comment: @gusto2  I have edited the question according to your comment and got the same length of string at least. Thanks for your comment and time... If you help me with IV creation it will be very helpful. Thanks once again.

Comment: IV should be random, not fixed, you may have a look ar openssl-random-pseudo-bytes. But I see you already have a program you have to mimick. To create a byte array in php you may use `pack` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved your code by using below code Hope this may help you

```
    public function encrypt($data, $key = "4A8A53E16C9C34EA5E77EF9FF7B2FD04", $method = "AES-256-CBC") {


                    $salt="178";

                    //Converting Array to bytes
                    $iv = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
                    $chars = array_map("chr", $iv);
                    $IVbytes = join($chars);


                    $salt1 = mb_convert_encoding($salt, "UTF-8"); //Encoding to UTF-8
                    $key1 = mb_convert_encoding($key, "UTF-8"); //Encoding to UTF-8

                    //SecretKeyFactory Instance of PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 Java Equivalent
                    $hash = openssl_pbkdf2($key1,$salt1,'256','65536', 'sha1'); 

                    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $hash, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IVbytes);

                    return bin2hex($encrypted);

}
```

Comment: Please note the solution not cryptographically secure. Using static IV with reusing the same key (having static salt) may not produce fully secure solution